# Limit of $0.n$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

Tags: limits

It's been a while I've been thinking about this question:
How does a number change? How 1 reaches 2 for example? Aren't there infinite numbers between these two? This may have more to do with the whole and the part subject in logic but I'd prefer mathematical approach; 
till I reached to this proof for 0.999 (infinite nines) is equal to 1:
[Proof for $0.999...=1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snbGl.jpg)

The problem I faced is that the proof supposes 9 for n and continues. Supposing any number for n only makes the growth speed different. What could be the general answer for the **limit of 0.n as n approaches infinity**?

I'm really curious if the answer could prepare an analytic approach for the first question as well.

Comment: See, we cannot discuss the value of quantities at infinity unless they are uniquely definable and consistent. If this is not the case, then we can only talk about such quantities as they approach infinity. For example, you can't talk about $0 \infty$, but you can certainly talk about $0n$ as $n \to \infty$, and the answer to that is zero. But $0 \infty = 0$ would create inconsistencies, so we avoid such an assignment.

Comment: *Numbers* do **not** change,"How 1 reaches 2 for example?" It does not : $1$ is one and $2$ is two and they stay apart forever and ever.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: You can think of it as a sequence

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then how do you walk on the earth? ;)

Comment: @ArashBK Then you are basically asking the question that I have mentioned and answered in my comment. As for how you walk the Earth, have you heard of Zeno's paradox? (Sum of infinite quantities can be finite). There may be infinitely many quantities between the two, but nothing stops a traversal in finite time.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг If you meant by your comment that 0.n is merging some sequences and is therefore inconsistent then "you mentioned and answered my question!" but your example doesn't match your intention well. I was looking at numbers as some entities that change as we constitute them. Mauro proposed another view which is interesting and implies that numbers exist in nature. The problem is closed to Zeno's one but isn't really the same. Accepting that view rises the question that how walking is possible (He can answer for example that walking is a bijective function just as counting is)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the point out.

Comment: Currently, this is not a question of limits or of mathematics, but a question of philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined. A way of seeing this is by noting that the subsequence $0.(10^k - 1 ) = 0.999\dots9$ converges to 1, while the subsequence $0.(10^k) = 0.1$ is a constant subsequence converging to $0.1$. Hence the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong.

> How 1 reaches 2 for example?

You are thinking that 1 is reaching 2 like 0.999… reaches 1. You could think that 0.9 is reaching 1 (since they are close enough and the separation between them is nearly 0) but you can't think that there will be 2 after 1 . There are a lot more numbers between them, like 1.0001.

In the case of natural numbers you can think 2 comes after 1.

Comment: You surprisingly got the underlying idea of my question which made me think about all this but your answer is a little bit simplistic. I really don't know myself if I'm looking the correct place (Maths) to solve such an old problem (the whole and the part paradox of human episteme) but it appears such to me.

Comment: @ArashBK if you think my this answers your question well,then you can re-accept any answer when ever you want.

Answer (score -2):

Let $ x = 0.999999....$

then $10x = 9.99999....$

then, $$10x = 9.999...$$
$$ - x = 0.999...$$
$$9x= 9.000...$$
$$x=1$$

See the [Hilbert Hotel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) for an illustration of why we can pull a 9 across to the units in 10x, and never have any missing 9 in the decimals

Comment: third line, there is a typo ! it's 0.9999....

Comment: That's a nice answer for this question: Why 0.999...=1 and Hilbert's Hotel is an example to explain there is not one infinity or why infinity in R is greater than infinity in N. My problem was sth else